# Simplify the logic

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Angular and going through some online courses and I'm trying to simplify below logic like using ternary operator etc..

```
onClick() {
    if (this.demo === true) {
      this.test = true;
    } else {
      this.test = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.test = this.demo === true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just assign the result of the check directly.

```
this.test = this.demo === true; // strict check for type and value
```

If `this.demo` is a boolean value, then only an assignment of this value is sufficient.

```
this.test = this.demo;
```